# How to ensure a logging file is flushed/closed within a DLL (C# and Serilog)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, serilog

I am currently experimenting with Serilog for logging to file and console, primarily for debugging purposes of a small C# DLL I am working on.

I am unsure how to go about Flushing/Closing the log file, i.e.:

```
Log.CloseAndFlush()
```

I could do it in the destructor, but other Stack Overflow articles suggest this is unwise as its execution is not guaranteed.

Other points:

- The Serilog Log is not publically exposed by the DLL class.
- What if the class is static ? (It is not but I am curious about the implications).

Comment: Why do you think you need to close and flush the log file? Eventually the framework, OS and disk will do this. More specifically, **when** do you want to do this, and again, why?

Comment: This is something to worry about a great deal, nobody needs a logger that can't flush its output by itself when the app crashes unexpectedly.  The author seems [very reluctant](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1111) to take care of it.  And sure, it is hard to do correctly.  But it doesn't get any easier for you.  Lots of logger libraries around, this one might not be your favorite.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Take this with a grain of salt, but my understanding is that leaving flushing/writing up to the OS is not guaranteed. As for the when and why, I just want to make sure I am covered after an app crash.

Comment: @HansPassant - Do you have any suggestions for an uncomplicated logger that would suit?  Preferably a logger that is configured entirely through code ie not log4net. I am just a hobbyist so I do not need anything to involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your DLL shouldn't make the choice of logging implementation library to use, but leave that up to the consumer of your library. Simply stick with an abstraction, most likely [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/), and its interfaces.

Generally, if you need the consumer to do any cleanup work related to your library, you should expose an explicit API to do so. Much like Serilog already does by exposing the `Log.CloseAndFlush()` method in the first place. Serilog (currently/arguably) simply doesn't know when to call it under all circumstances and so "simply" leaves that task for the consumer (ultimately an application/executable).

Consider:

```
namespace YourLibrary 
{
   public static class Util
   {
       public static void Shutdown()
       {
           // Potentially other stuff...

           // Cleanup logging
           Log.CloseAndFlush();
       }
   }
}
```

Then in you require your consumers to do something like this (example):

```
public static void Main()
{
   try
   {
      // ... whatever ...
   }
   finally
   {
      YourLibrary.Util.Shutdown();
   }
}
```

This design is not optimal from a usage point of view, but at least it makes things explicit.

In the end, however, there will always be situations when you cannot have your cleanup method being called (crashes, etc.), so I would suggest what Hans said in his comment: look for a different logging framework implementation (or choose a Serilog Sink that always flushes implicitly).

Comment: Thankyou I think I understand now. I will attempt to use an abstraction in future. I will also look for a better logging framework, if you have any suggestions (preferably configurable entirely from within code, ie no config files like log4net) I would appreciate it.

Comment: Personally, I don't think that Serilog is a _bad_ logging framework - quite the contrary actually. But you have to make sure that you use the right Sinks for your needs. File sinks often do buffered writing for performance reasons; if that is not tolerable make sure it flushes on every write. Also asynchronous sinks might take some time to flush the log records they have queued. But that again, they have better performance characteristics as they don't block the main app while actually writing. YMMV ;-)

Comment: Looking into an appropriate sink now. I actually quite like Serilog (based on my limited experience), so if I can keep using it I will.  I would mark this question as answered if I had the rep to do it :) Thanks for your help.